# Ubuntu 16.04 not reading HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have an HP Pavilion m7 with Windows 10 Pro Dual boot/Ubuntu 16.04. When powered off before, sometimes I would get to the GRUB only to see that it told me to
**error: you need to upload the kernel first.**
Now, everytime I press the power button I am **always** getting:

**error: unknown filesystem**
**grub rescue>**

Not only that, it seems like Ubuntu isn't reading my HDD at all, for some odd reason. I'm a newbie at this, excuse me for the headache I am causing.

I tried Boot-Repair on a Live CD, still haven't had any success nor luck from cracking this problem. Any help, pointers, or eggs with smiley faces would be accepted! :)

I was given an pastebin from the Boot-Repair. https://paste.ubuntu.com/26309271/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the attached logs, it would appear the the main drive (/dev/sda) is failing. At the very least, the early sectors have been corrupted or overwritten since the repair utility does not detect an MBR.

You have successfully booted a USB stick, so you can use the "Disks" application [to check the disk for S.M.A.R.T. errors](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html).

If the drive is physically OK, it is still logically ruined. If you need data from it, you will need to engage some kind of disk data rescue service. If you don't need the data on the drive, you can just attempt a fresh re-install and overwrite the existing contents.

Comment: Everytime I attempt to open up "Disks", it immediately force closes. Doesn't even open, any other suggestion?

Comment: From the pastebin, it looks like a ST1000LM024 drive. Get the SEATOOLS DOS-based ISO image, burn to CD or USB, boot it, and see if it can run diagnostics on the Seagate drive. [Seatools](https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/)

Comment: Worked just like a Charm ! Thank you very much both of you. :)